# iOS 14.4 : An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14

I am getting the following error when trying to hit https://api.github.com/users.

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

I have added the following config in Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>filename.hostname.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Config:

- iOS simulator 14.4
- XCode 12.4
- Swift 4.2
- Server https://api.github.com/users

Comment: Please share some code to help debug the issue. Since the request is HTTPS you shouldn’t be getting this error, so there is likely a bug in your networking code, firewall setup, network connection or authentication.

Comment: I have put these lines of code to fetch data
`let urlString: String = "https://api.github.com/users"
        guard let url: URL = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        var urlRequest: URLRequest =  URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
}.resume()`

Comment: Please update the question with the code instead.